# C# : Selenium firefox probleme

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium

I am trying to open the **firefox** browser using Selenium.

This is my first time with selenium, I want my c# application to discover if any facebook page on any browser (**Chrome** , **IE** , **Firefox**) is opened.

But when I try to navigate with firefox I had the following error message: (" **An error occurred while connecting to firefox**")

I am looking for any suggestions that experts might have.

This is The code:

```
    using OpenQA.Selenium;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

    IWebDriver driver  = new FirefoxDriver();
```

PS : it's 100% worked with IE and Chrome
What can I do?

Comment: Try updating the version of firefox you have installed.

Comment: i want to share my application with friends and user .... and i want it to work with any firefox version ...
thank you

Answer (score 0):

@Bassem Alrefaie: What all you have references set in your project? references in the form of dll's.

You must include the dll's castle.core ; Newtonsoft.Json. Try using these dll's and then check.

Answer (score 0):

We were having a problem with Firefox, turned out version 45.0.1 wasn't compatible with our older version of Selenium.  Either downgrading Firefox or updating Selenium should fix the problem.